# mpdf ignores my fontsize in my css

Tags: css, mpdf

i use the latest version of mPDF 7. I have created a template with HTML and CSS for a A4 page everything looks fine.
But mPDF makes a lot different. The biggest Problem is that mPDF is ignoring my font size attributes in the css.
For my font I use the corefont paramter. Could it be that this is the problem?

In my CSS I have also declared this in my CSS file:

```
@page {
    sheet-size: A4;
    header: mpdfFooter;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

body {
    line-height: 1.25;
    color: #140b54;
    font-family: 'helvetica neue', 'arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 9pt;
}

.senderAdress { //this filesize will be ignored
    display: block;
    font-size: 6pt;
}
```

If this problem will be solved I would be a milestone further.

Cheers

Comment: How are you setting the `font-size`? It's not set in your above code. If you set it inside of a `@media screen` then it will indeed be ignored.

Comment: Hi, okay it is not ignoring it on the body element but on some other elements.
Can it be that mPDF had some problems with nested elements?

I create invoices and I have in the address field a really small sender adress (6pt). But it is rendered in the body font-size.